# Counting the number of records if a check box field is not checked and and a date field is less than a year from now

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm not sure if I'm in the right approach but I want to count those records on tbl1 whose field is a checkBox field is not checked or the field checkDate is older than 365 days from today's date.

```
Private Sub Form_Current ()
Dim checkCounter As integer
checkCounter = DCount("[checkBox]", "tbl1", "[checkBox] = 
FALSE AND Today(Date) - [checkDate]>365)
lblCount.Caption = checkCounter
End Sub
```

Or is there a better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```vb
checkCounter = DCount("*", "tbl1", "[checkBox] = FALSE AND DateDiff('d', [checkDate], Date()) > 365")
```

Comment: works great thanks. I have been wondering, is there a reason why the 'd' in the DateDiff() function not as many describe, "d"? I tried 
`checkCounter = DCount("*", "tbl1", "[checkBox] = FALSE AND DateDiff("d", [checkDate], Date) > 365")` but did not work. Your code worked straight away!

Comment: That's because you have the `'d'` inside the filter string. Using `"d"` (double-quotes) will mess that up.

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers!